# Why do we need Repository in Spring Boot Applications

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to spring boot, and recently started learning it, I have a question why do we create a repository in spring boot applications. Can anyone please explain to me logically?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In order to use it to access data in most cases.

Comment: It is an implementation of DAO pattern. Check on that.

Answer (score 0):

We build app to present data. These data may be static and small(In case we don't need Database).

But if want to store it some where and get it from somewhere we need services your service with use some data or consume some services.

So whenever to want to have a controller over the data and want to store it for future use you have to store to. To control the data you use repository.

Answer (score 0):

when we want to work with data sources to perform CRUD operation,querying etc...so for these purpose it is the best option to use repository.